# If $\lim_{x \to a} cf(x) = cL$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

#### Claim:

If $$\lim_{x \to a} cf(x) = cL$$ then $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$ where $c > 0$.

#### Proof:

Suppose that $\lim_{x \to a} cf(x) = cL$ with $c>0$.

This means that for all $\epsilon_0 > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, then $|cf(x)-cL| < \epsilon_0$. Taking $\epsilon = \epsilon_0/c$. Then $$|f(x) - L| = \frac{1}{c}(c|f(x) - L|) = \frac{1}{c} |c||f(x) - L| = \frac{1}{c} |cf(x)-cL| < \frac{\epsilon_0}{c} = \epsilon$$

Using $0< |x-a| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, this proves that $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

#### Question

Does this seems valid? Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good to me. Well done!

Next it is proposed a slightly more straightforward approach.

The existence of the proposed limit corresponds to the claim:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a}cf(x) = cL & \Rightarrow (\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists\delta_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\forall x\in D_{f})(0 < |x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |cf(x) - cL| < c\varepsilon)\\\\
& \Rightarrow (\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists\delta_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\forall x\in D_{f})(0 < |x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon)\\\\
& \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L
\end{align*}

where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $D_{f}$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I think you made an error not assuming or saying about $c$, which should be positive.

Comment: Dear @JoshuaOrtiz, I have taken it for granted as you have already mentioned in the body of the question that $c > 0$. I can edit it if you think it is necessary, though.

Comment: Alright! Thanks anyway!